# Link between partial and Frechet derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Searching for a some connection between the partial derivative and the Frechet derivative.

Comment: Take a look at (differentiability in higher dimensions)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions]. There you see a similarity.

Comment: The partial derivatives are the Frechet derivative expansion when the function is defined on a product of Frechet spaces.